# BouncyCastle tlsutils checkVersion

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle

BouncyCastle `org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsUtils` has the following methods

```
protected static void checkVersion(InputStream inputstream, TlsProtocolHandler tlsprotocolhandler)
    throws IOException
{
    int i = inputstream.read();
    int j = inputstream.read();
    if (i != 3 || j != 1)
    {
        tlsprotocolhandler.failWithError((short)2, (short)70);
    }
}

protected static void checkVersion(byte abyte0[], TlsProtocolHandler tlsprotocolhandler)
    throws IOException
{
    if (abyte0[0] != 3 || abyte0[1] != 1)
    {
        tlsprotocolhandler.failWithError((short)2, (short)70);
    }
}
```

What is the 3 & 1 being checked here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good example of a bad thing called "magic numbers" :-) 
Excerpt from the javadoc of `InputStream.read()`:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
>   returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available
>   because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is
>   returned.

That means `i` and `j` are the version numbers read from the stream. And them just have to be version `3` and version `1`. Also the `failWithError` method gets passed magic numbers. The `TlsProtocolHandler` has constants for them, I have no idea why the authors don't use them

```
2: AL_fatal
70: AP_protocol_version
```

[source](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/TlsProtocolHandler.java.html)

Looking at the code `checkVersion` is called while the handshake phase (`ServerHello`). Here the protocol version is checked. See the version chapter of this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_record) to find the version numbers. Major version 3, minor version 1 is `TLS 1.0`.

Comment: What are 3 & 1 the version numbers of?

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this mean bouncy castle doesn't support TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.2?

Comment: Newer versions as yours seems to support TLS 1.1 and 1.2. They changed this validation mechanism. The current sources have a [ProtocolVersion](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/ProtocolVersion.java) class.